# Android Studio download cancels every single time

Tags: android, networking, download

[image]
Whenever I try to download android studio for Linux, when last second is left it shows network error. I tried it 5 times and same thing happened. At the last second the download cancels and it shows "unknown network error". I have tried downloading on Windows and Ubuntu but the result was same. I was able to download android studio for Windows without any problem.

Comment: solved it by downloading with torrent :)

Comment: Really need an answer to this! Can't download torrents at work unfortunately. Do you think it's a chrome problems. Coz I had the same problem on chrome windows 7?

Comment: the same was happening also on mozilla firefox. So i don't think it is specifically a crome problem.

Comment: Are you sure? I finally completed it on Internet Explorer 10. It got stuck again at 97%, but I paused and then immediately resumed the download. Worked after that.

Comment: Same problem, please a solution!

Comment: similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025322/unknown-network-error-while-downloading-android-studio/36588000#36588000 see my solution

Comment: I finished this job with secret tab or secret window  in chrome and whale browser in windows 10

Answer (score 3):

Downloading with Chrome on Windows 10 failed 4 times at around 95% Pause/resume dose not help firewall disabling dose not help trying Firefox
Firefox retry works great and resume downloading
just **Use Firefox to download this file**

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a problem in such downloads itself,regardless of the browser or the antivirus and all...
Download it using Internet Download Manager.
press Ctrl+J ->opens downloads folder...
right click on the link which says "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.0.1/android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe" (Encircled in red in the image)
then copy the link address and paste the same in Internet Download Manager.
after 4 hours it still remains at 99.99%...
Pause the download and start again...
This time it completes ..100%
And all the downloaded files get appended to one file.

The actual problem occurs in transferring the downloaded files from cache to your system folder.Resuming the download somehow overrides this.
No need to diable firewall or antivirus in this method.

Comment: Sorry cud'nt upload the image .It Requires 10 reputation points which i do not have.

Comment: Ha ha, thankyou!! Glad that you are a well wisher.@Zeb-ur-Rehman

Answer (score 1):

OR use the zipped download from [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.0.1/android-studio-ide-135.1641136-windows.zip) and then extract it and run the .exe file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading with Chrome on Win 7 failed all the time for me. I tried with Firefox, and although it gave the same error, I was able to finish the download with "Retry" button in Downloads in Firefox, because it downloads not from the beginning of the file, but resumes the downloading.

So install Firefox and retry the download until it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same difficulty with Firefox on Ubuntu. Downloading the command via console is what ultimately worked for me:

1. First, determine the download file URL. This can be found by right-clicking the button which initiates the download, and clicking "Copy Link Location". Mine was the following, but **NOTE THAT OVER TIME THE FOLLOWING WILL BECOME OUTDATED, AND YOU SHOULD FIND THE URL YOURSELF; THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE:**

   ```
   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
   ```
2. Having placed this link in my clipboard, I opened up a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T, or launch the "Terminal" program), navigated to my `Downloads` folder (`cd ~/Downloads`), then used `wget` to download the file:

   ```
   wget "http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz"
   ```

   **NOTE AGAIN THAT THE ABOVE URL SHOULD BE REPLACED WITH THE CURRENT URL; THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE**.
   `wget` is a standard linux command that downloads a file from the source URL into the current folder. Anyway, this solved my problem! If, for extra certainty, you want to verify your download, you can use the `sha1sum` command:

   ```
   sha1sum android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
   ```

   **(You'll need to change the filename above if the version numbers change)**. This will print the SHA-1 checksum, which the android studio website includes in the page where you select your platform (currently here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other). If the two strings match, then it is extremely likely that your download is a success!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

1. Disable your firewall
2. When you are downloading, a minute or two before it finishes, pause the download and resume after 1 minute.
3. ENJOY. IT WILL WORK JUST FINE!!!

Comment: Found another posting mentioning it's a chrome issue, used MS Edge to download and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025322/unknown-network-error-while-downloading-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a Chrome issue, at least the Windows 10 version of Chrome. Using Microsoft Edge or maybe another solves the problem. I used Edge and it downloaded without any pauses or hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when downloading the full kit 'android studio IDE + JDK 7.0', the reason is JDK 7.0 being on another server and it's possible that google server uses proxy settings that blocks traffic when downloading - I am not sure yet.

The only way around it is to dowload 'android studio IDE' only, during the installation you will be given a link and prompted to install JDK 7.0 on Oracle website, so do that as well.

That did the trick.

PS: For anyone suggesting disabling the firewall while connected to the internet for the period of the download, well ..

Answer (score 0):

Just use download accelerator to download ... I used DAP [From here](http://www.speedbit.com/dap/)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Chrome and Firefox -> the last kb or so refused to download.

Solution was simply to change the name of the downloaded file:

I removed the <.part> from the filename (android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows.exe.part) and it worked.

Edit: I have now used Android Studio for several weeks without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is the old post, but I'm still facing with this issue. The workaround for me was to download zipped version of Android studio from softpedia.com (http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Android-Studio.shtml#download)

I know that this not helping solving the issue, but might help to download the file.