# Unknown network error while downloading Android Studio

Tags: android

I am learning development of Android Apps and trying to download **Android studio**  which is 824MB from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio in Chrome and I am leading to the Unknown network error at the end of download. when I see download manager in chrome, notice the following entry

android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exeUnknown network error.
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.0.1/android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe

I tried couple of times , but no luck in downloading successfully.

Please show me pointers on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yeah today i have also tried 3 times but i think there is a problem from the official site or may be some slow network related issue.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I was able to download it successfully through BitComet.

Comment: Chrome was not downloading so tried Tor browser and same link worked

Answer (score 11):

This is a known bug in Chrome see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66339 or
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78241

> Note that the workaround is to use IE or Firefox to download the file.

Comment: I also had this same problem downloading with FF, now I will try with IE

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Android Studio v2 when trying to download from the main site eg: [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html](http://MAIN_SITE) from Ubuntu using Chrome or Firefox.

What worked for me (Ubuntu, both Chrome and Firefox) was to go to the builds site: [http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds](http://BUILDS) and pick the build you are after or for V2 Stable, you can go straight here:[http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0](http://STABLE_V2_THIS_WORKS)

Answer (score 0):

Upon file completed download, Chrome will try to rename temp download file to proper file name. This is where it fails. So Just rename the downloaded file extension to ".exe" and run it. I installed it successfully.